# Dictionary Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, python

New to code golf and enjoying it. I have a problem that I cannot figure out and am curious if others can solve it.

Start with two dictionaries, `y` and `z`:

```py
y = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 5, 'g': 7}
z = {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'f': 6, 'h': 8}
```

`y` and `z` both map length-1 strings to numbers, where each number is between 1 and 26 (inclusive) and represents an English letter: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 , ... , z = 26.

The goal is as follows:

1. Double each number (i.e. value) in `y`, and replace the key with the letter corresponding to the new number.
2. Do the same for `z`, but triple each number instead.
3. Populate a dictionary `x` with the keys and values from both `y` and `z` in descending numerical order, for instance:

```py
x = {'x': 24, 'n':18, 'm': 14, 'l':12, 'j': 10, 'f': 6, 'b':2}
```

Good luck!

Example:

Starting state:

```py
y = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 5, 'g': 7}
z = {'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'f': 6, 'h': 8}
```

After `y` operations:

```py
y = {'b':2, 'f': 6, 'j': 10, 'm': 14}
```

After `z` operations:

```py
z = {'f': 6, 'l': 12, 'n': 18, 'x': 24}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82334/discussion-on-question-by-julian-silvestri-dictionary-code-golf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Python, <strike>174</strike> <strike>155</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>86</strike> <strike>70</strike> <strike>68</strike> 66 bytes

It's actually my first time here and here's my attempt. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

```
lambda y,z:{chr(v*(3-v%2)+96):v*(3-v%2)for v in{**y,**z}.values()}
```

**EDIT**: After OP's edit and @Rod 's comment I noticed I have some mistakes. I also took out the sorting attempts because it simply can't work with Python dictionaries.

**EDIT2**: -16bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchLDsIgAIThq7AxPEQTi1Yl8SZu6APbpNIGKwklnB1n5er7Z5a4DrNTxT6eZTLvpjMkyk2ndvAsCKYOYVfx/b3m@r/s7Ekgo0tCRCnElo/BTN/@w3guix/dyixL1FBNTpLQFirYwwt8wWuWJNEGVeHp4BlaWMMB3jLn5Qc)

Comment: Just so you know, at the moment this is a TIPS question, not a challenge. Please add an explanation to your answer.